# how to show the date only when the time is 12:00 AM on the xaxis jquery flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I want to label the x-axis of a jquery.flot graph showing the time in increments of 1 hour. When the time passes midnight I would like to show the date and the time.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DNS suggests, use the tickFormatter for this.  Something like:

```
tickFormatter: function formatter(val, axis) {
  var d = new Date(val);
  var rV = null;          
  if (lastDay == null) //lastDay is a global, set to null outside of plot call
  {
    rV = $.plot.formatDate(d, "%H:%M"); // first date return time
  }
  else
  {
     if (d.getDay() == 1 || d.getDay() > lastDay.getDay())  // we have a new day
     {
     rV = $.plot.formatDate(d, "<b>New Day</b></br> %m/%d"); // return different format
     }
     else  // same day, just time
     {
     rV = $.plot.formatDate(d, "%H:%M");
     }
  }
  lastDay = d; 
  return rV;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set `tickSize` (or `minTickSize`, depending on how you want your labels to behave) to `[1, "hour"]`, then provide a `tickFormatter` function that produces a label if the date falls on midnight, otherwise an empty string.